# Is destroySession (PHP SDK ) still useful with Facebook API 2.0?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

in some old code I have a a couple of

```
$facebook->destroySession();
```

statements used to clean the facebook session. I've noticed that `destroySession` is not available anymore in the last PHP SDK, is there any equivalent?

Comment: I am also facing such proble, and didn't get any solution till now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No equivalent , it's deprecated after PHP SDK 3.2.3 , current SDK is 4.0.0
This method main purpose is to Logout user from Facebook graph , in old version user may Logout from Facebook and login with different account but in Facebook graph API it still use the old account , so this method was the fix .

But current Facebook graph didn't need that , once you Logout from your account it logs you out from graph API too .

[Deprecated destroySession method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-destroySession/4.0.0)